# How do I make the image show as a background to the table and not the body?

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, vml

I know Outlook does not really render images for background but using the Bulletproof Background I found, I managed to add a background. However, I wanted the background to only be within the table (which is 600px). It works in every other email but Outlook (I use Outlook 2010 so it probably doesn't work in Outlook 2007-2016 as well). In Outlook, the background spans the whole body, not just the table.

I've tried adding the background image in td but the image still goes beyond the table.

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-image:url('image-here');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:top;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" background="image-here">
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
                    <v:fill type="tile" src="image-here" color="#ffffff" />
                    </v:background>
                <![endif]-->
                    <table>
                         content here
                    </table>            
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hmm...  it's a little unclear what you're saying here.. Are you saying that Outlook won't render using css style declarations, but using vendor tags and vector markup you're able to render an image, but still doesn't adhere to the style declarations.  So.. what is your question? How does one apply css style declarations to vml in this scenario? ... also, is this a raterized image or vector image?

Comment: You need to set widths and heights on background images. I'd imagine if you're seeing your background image working, you have set these? If that is the case, can you please post your actual code. Will help us debug properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing you inline style in table tag.

```
<table class="table" style="background-image: url('image-here');">
```

Comment: Defining the background image on the table doesn't make a difference as the table cell is just inheriting the width from the table.